# Android Smack Xmpp connection handling best practices

Tags: android, service, connection, xmpp, smack

I've been using **Smack XMPP** android library for **chat** application.

My current architecture for chat is ,I use **XMPP** to send **messages** to client only if the app is in **Foreground** otherwise use **GCM**. Server is already handled properly.

Since android doesn't have method to simply indicate where the app is currently in FG or BG, I find difficult connecting and disconnecting XMPP . So I implemented using timer on each activity **onPause** and **onResume** when the app has more than one activities.This is very painful and lot more work to do.

For eg , I have two activities, **A and B**.Connect XMPP in **onResume()** of **A** .Switch from **A** to **B**, **onPause()** will trigger on **A** and disconnect XMPP connection after 3sec.Within 3sec , **onResume()** of **B** will trigger and stop the timer so that connection will be alive . :-)

**onPause()**

```
if (Application.getInstance().xmppStatus == XMPPSTATUS.CONNECTED) {
     Application.getInstance().disconnectXmpp(); //disconnect xmpp after 3sec
}
```

**onResume()**

```
if (Application.getInstance().xmppStatus == XMPPSTATUS.DISCONNECTED) {
     LoginHelper.connectXmpp();//connect XMPP 
}
```

I believe that most of you have fallen into this kind of issue esp in chat so i would very appreciate to hear your experiences on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should not disconnect client manually, just switch to gcm when client disconnected from server and switch back to xmpp when client connected again, all logic should be on server side

Comment: firstly server is not maintained by me. Secondly how shd server know whether client disconnect or not? For now there is new notification to send , server check whether client is offline ( disconnect XMPP ) or Online ( XMPP connected ).base on that server will use GCM for offline and use XMPP otherwise

Comment: server "know" about every connected client and you should trigger switch to gcm on every disconnection from server, even if it was unclear (without sending "disconnect" status), just because user can lost connection at any time

Comment: thanks for answer @vitalyster . having said that when shd i switch to GCM from client ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is you should use Fragments instead of Activities. If you use fragments then you will have only 1 Activity and your onPause() and onResume() handling will be very easy. Give it a try.... Fragments are more faster than activities.